# Find all possible positions for a wildcard in string

Tags: combinations, wildcard, permutation, string-function

Let's say I have the string "hello" now I would like find all possible combinations to replace each character in the string with a wildcard. Where string length -1 wildcards are possible (4 in example).

e.g

```
_ello
h_llo
he_lo
hel_o
hell_
__llo
_e_lo
```

etc. (should be 30 possible one in this case)

Are there any simple algorithms for this?

Comment: What kind of programming/scripting language are you using?

Comment: can be java or sqlscript